# C# - How to set SharePoint permissions for user under subsite not Root level

Tags: c#, sharepoint, permissions

I'm trying to add permissions for a user that is under a subsite in SharePoint. I was able to successfully set the permissions for the user on the root level, but I am not sure how to approach the problem for a lower level subsite. Below is what I have at the moment but it crashes although it shows no error building in VS. Any ideas would be great

```
        foreach (SPWeb subSite in spSite2.RootWeb.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser())
        {
            if (subSite.Name == "templates")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nTEMPLATES SITE");
                Console.Write("\nApplying 'Read' permission to App_user Account");
                spRoleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(SPContext.Current.Web.Users[appUserAccount]);
                spRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(SPContext.Current.Web.RoleDefinitions["Read"]);
                SPContext.Current.Web.RoleAssignments.Add(spRoleAssignment);
                SPContext.Current.Web.Update();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.CursorLeft = Console.BufferWidth - 16; Console.WriteLine("Applied");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to achieve nor where your code is supposed to be executed (console application or timer job or in a web part?).

I see the following problems:

1. You log to the console (which let's me assume your code runs in a console application), but you access the `SPContext.Current`, which is only available if your code runs in a HTTP request.
2. You are iterating over a collection of webs. But in your for-each body the `SPContext.Current.Web` is updated.
3. You do retrieve your web collection via the `web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser()`, but are then changing permissions on these objects. This smells a little since updating permissions is an "admin task" and the the method `GetSubwebsForCurrentUser` is more likely to be used for a low level user context to avoid access denied exception. For instance to safely display a list of webs.
4. You do update permissions/roles on a web, but a check if the web has unique role assignments is missing.
5. You check for a web with the name "templates". Since `GetSubwebsForCurrentUser` is not recursive there can only be one web named "templates" in this collection. This web can be opened direclty => no need to waste resource by opening every sub web.

If your task is to set role permissions on a given web "templates" (which is a 1st level sub web of your root web) you can use the follwing code:

```
// Open the web directly since it is a direct child of the site collection.
// Use a using to properly release the resources
using (SPWeb web = spSite2.Open("templates"))
{
  SPUser user = web.SiteUsers[appUserAccount];
  SPRoleDefinition roleDef = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);

  if (!web.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
  {
    web.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
  }

  spRoleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(user);
  spRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDef);
  web.RoleAssignments.Add(spRoleAssignment);

  // No need to update the web when changing the permissions
}
```

Comment: hi jason, thanks. how can i use this for a document library that is a subsite of the subsite templates?

Comment: how can I edit the using statement for a document library?? I think thats an SPLIst

Comment: Just get the list: `SPList list = web.Lists["your list title goes here"]`. On the list object you can do the same permission management as on `SPWeb`. You do not have to dispose the `SPList` object. So no using statement is required.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update roles in the subSite, not in the current web from SPContext?

AFAIK each SPWeb object have it's own roles assignments.